# Fabric Digits: logout for web

Tags: web, logout, twitter-fabric, twitter-digits

I created a login for my site using [Docs Digits Sign in with Phone Number](https://docs.fabric.io/web/digits/getting-started.html)

Login is working fine. How should I add Logout link on my site?